# javascript fix tree array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

hello i have json array

its family tree

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5c789fd2952b2353b4eba417",
    "level": 1,
    "children": [
      {
        "_id": "5c78a09a0dd5f05134b7a7ce",
        "level": 2,
        "children": [
          {
            "_id": "5c78a0a70dd5f05134b7a7d3",
            "level": 3,
            "children": []
          }]}]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5c78a08a0dd5f05134b7a7c9",
    "level": 1,
    "children": []
  }
]
```

i want convert it to be like this

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5c789fd2952b2353b4eba417",
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "5c78a09a0dd5f05134b7a7ce",
    "level": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "5c78a0a70dd5f05134b7a7d3",
    "level": 3
  },
  {
    "_id": "5c78a08a0dd5f05134b7a7c9",
    "level": 1
  }
]
```

any good function to fix it ?????

i try many way but if have more children i need add so much code :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a recursive function using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Code:

```js
const data = [{"_id": "5c789fd2952b2353b4eba417","level": 1,"children": [{"_id": "5c78a09a0dd5f05134b7a7ce","level": 2,"children": [{"_id": "5c78a0a70dd5f05134b7a7d3","level": 3,"children": []}]}]},{"_id": "5c78a08a0dd5f05134b7a7c9","level": 1,"children": []}];
const getResult = array => array.reduce((a, c) => {
  a.push({ _id: c._id, level: c.level });
  return c.children.length ? [...a, ...getResult(c.children)] : a;
}, []);

console.log(getResult(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package: [Github] https://github.com/mwc/treeify

[NPM] https://www.npmjs.com/package/treeify-js

Installation:

$ npm install --save-dev treeify-js

The treeify package has an **untreeify** API used to convert a tree object to flat array.